# Dockerized zkSync testing environment image fails with error Solidity 0.8.19 is not fully supported yet

Tags: hardhat, solc, docker, zksync

I'm setting up a dockerized local `zksync` testing environment according to this guide [here](https://era.zksync.io/docs/tools/testing/dockerized-testing.html#dockerized-local-setup-installation-setup). When I run the `./start.sh` command, it runs all three images but the `local-setup-zksync-1` image exits with status code 139 after some time. I get an error message:

> Solidity 0.8.19 is not fully supported yet. You can still use Hardhat, but some features, like stack traces, might not work correctly.

Here are the logs from Docker:

```
.
.
.
2023-10-04 18:21:36 ✔ Initializing L1 Allow list done (9005ms)
2023-10-04 18:21:36 
2023-10-04 18:21:36 ------------------------
2023-10-04 18:21:36 > Deploying L2 contracts
$ hardhat compile
2023-10-04 18:21:38 Solidity 0.8.19 is not fully supported yet. You can still use Hardhat, but some features, like stack traces, might not work correctly.
2023-10-04 18:21:38 
2023-10-04 18:21:38 Learn more at https://hardhat.org/hardhat-runner/docs/reference/solidity-support
2023-10-04 18:21:38 
2023-10-04 18:21:39 Downloading solc 0.8.19
2023-10-04 18:21:40 Segmentation fault
error Command failed with exit code 139.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
2023-10-04 18:21:40 Error: Child process exited with code 139
```

Tried reinstalling Docker, clearing and starting the images with and without root permissions but it did not work.

(Im on a Macbook Pro 2020 i7)